# Can't Delete Youtube Subscription With API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have the code setup for the Youtube API with oauth login. Login appears to work properly. I can even see the requests hitting my analytics. However, when I run the code to unsubscribe from a channel, it never works on any channel ID I give it. It should be noted that [I'm using the exact example from googles dev docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/delete)(see "full sample" option for javascript)... I'm guessing the code is correct and this is some other auth/lookup problem.

---

**API code:**

```
 alert("deleting steven!!!!!!");
 buildApiRequest('DELETE',
               '/youtube/v3/subscriptions',
               {'id': 'UCMtFAi84ehTSYSE9XoHefig'});
```

**Stock Youtube API Code:**

```
function executeRequest(request) {
    request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  function buildApiRequest(requestMethod, path, params, properties) {
    params = removeEmptyParams(params);
    var request;
    if (properties) {
      var resource = createResource(properties);
      request = gapi.client.request({
          'body': resource,
          'method': requestMethod,
          'path': path,
          'params': params
      });
    } else {
      request = gapi.client.request({
          'method': requestMethod,
          'path': path,
          'params': params
      });
    }
    executeRequest(request);
  }
```

---

**Here is the error:**

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.subscription",
    "reason": "subscriptionNotFound",
    "message": "The subscription that you are trying to delete cannot be found. Check the value of the requests \u003ccode\u003eid\u003c/code\u003e parameter to ensure that it is correct."
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "The subscription that you are trying to delete cannot be found. Check the value of the requests \u003ccode\u003eid\u003c/code\u003e parameter to ensure that it is correct."
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Weird enough, it is working on some ids

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'm hoping someone from google will respond... good to know I'm not alone :)

Comment: FYI: I've opened a ticket with google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112843219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the ID you have to send is not the channel ID. It's the ID of the subscriptions.
You can get it by sending request to check your subscriptions with the channel. For example

**Request:**

```
buildApiRequest('GET',
                '/youtube/v3/subscriptions',
                {'forChannelId': 'UCEhZglE9MQ4zTL5ErNXt5mg',
                'mine': 'true',
                'part': 'snippet,contentDetails'});
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#subscription",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/KrR9MNb4Xs1eNjWMxAH-f5ccsos\"",
  "id": "Xmg72z6q83hK2hjx0J4ZwNVcgGz8fu9JCjeHu6eIb3M",
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-09-30T16:51:47.000Z",
    "title": "Rebeca Willett",
    "description": "",
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "channelId": "UCEhZglE9MQ4zTL5ErNXt5mg"
    },
    "channelId": "UCWfZYaoFrUOSoHNhCOOqKCQ",
    "thumbnails": {
    ...
}
```

Using ID in the response to send request for unsubscribing:

```
buildApiRequest('DELETE',
                '/youtube/v3/subscriptions',
                {'id': 'Xmg72z6q83hK2hjx0J4ZwNVcgGz8fu9JCjeHu6eIb3M'});
```

Here is the [google docs for getting subscriptions ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)